# Deleting lines in File with "inplace"

Tags: windows, gawk, inplace-editing

Another question that I have is how to manipulate text files.

I joined several files to one big. Now I have all headlines of the files in the new big one and want to delete them in the file without saving under a new one.

My file is separated by ";" and used to stay separated by ";"

I searched and found a oneliner here: [How to find lines matching a pattern and delete them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587264/how-to-find-lines-matching-a-pattern-and-delete-them)

I tried it in my cmd (I'm running windows) and get the error message:

> gawk: fatal: can't open source file `inplace' for reading (No such file or directory)

My codeline is:

```
gawk -i inplace "!/^Address (CO)/" filename.txt
```

I don't find anything about how to alternate it to Windows, if there is something special except for changing ' to "".
All the headline contain the work "Address (CO)" in first column.

Sample of my Input:

> Address (CO) - Costumer - Phone_Number
>   Mainstreet 1 - Carl Monte - 123456
>   Mainstreet 2 - Anja Coleman - 407846
>   Address (CO) - Costumer - Phone_Number
>   Mainstreet 10 - Sebastian Wol - 756189
>   Mainstreet 7 - Dennis Mann - 694311
>   Address (CO) - Costumer - Phone_Number
>   ...

Desired Output:

> Address (CO) - Costumer - Phone_Number
>   Mainstreet 1 - Carl Monte - 123456
>   Mainstreet 2 - Anja Coleman - 407846
>   Mainstreet 10 - Sebastian Wol - 756189
>   Mainstreet 7 - Dennis Mann - 694311
>   ...

So "just" delete the lines that contain "Address" but not the first appearance.

I also tried that oneliner:

```
gawk "!/Address/" filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

But my output is the same content like my input. So filename.txt == newfile.txt. It's not deleting anything.

Adding my Output doing the following:
I'm converting several csv files to txt using

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir XLS\*.xls /s /b') do copy "%%f" ".\TXT\%%~nf.txt"
```

Afterward I'm using a powershellscript to exchange tab delimeter to semicolon using:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir TXT\*.txt /b /s') do powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file %powershellscript% -path "%%i" -outPath "Output\%%~nxi"
```

Now I have several txt files with a semicolon separator in one folder. All of them with the same header. For merging them together without header into one "bigfile" I tried:

```
(for %%F in (Output\*.txt) do @more +1 "%%F") > output.txt
```

What is not working. I tried as well:

```
copy *.txt merged_tempfile.txt
gawk -F";" -v OFS=";" "$1 !~ /Address (CO)/ {print}" merged_tempfile.txt > bigfile.txt
```

What is not working as well...
When I try to use

```
gawk dos2unix file1  
gawk "!/Address (CO)/" file1.txt > temp1.txt
```

I only get the same content in temp1 like in file1, with this in last column.

> ਍圀嘀圀娀娀娀䄀䄀娀䔀䐀㤀　㄀㌀㄀㐀㬀攀ⴀ甀瀀℀        栀椀最栀   㘀　     䔀㄀䘀㬀䔀䰀㄀㬀攀ⴀ刀攀洀漀琀攀㬀䈀圀㔀㬀一漀琀爀甀昀洀漀搀甀氀 匀圀ⴀ嘀攀爀猀椀漀渀㬀　㄀　㌀ഀഀ

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish (IHMO). (yes, I know, "in place"). But edit your Q to show 2-3 lines of 40 chars of sample input and required output from the same inputs. Maybe we can help then. For 99% of the time, "in-place" editting is a false god and impossibility, so you might also want to explain why you think that is important. Good luck.

Comment: I edited my Q. For me it's not important to use inplace. I just read it and thought maybe it's more comfortable to alternate the file without writing a new one. And so far my other alternative with "!/Address/" is not working at all. And ofc I was interested for this function. Maybe in future I will need it and then I already know how to use it and don't have to search for information.

Comment: Thanks for the update! `gawk "!/Address/"` works for me. If your file was created or passed thru MS-Windows, then pre-process it with `dos2unix file`. Then rerun and let me know results. Good luck.

Comment: I treid it with one file. Actually I get the files in csv (tab delimited) convert it to txt and want to take out the headers. I found some code in batch for merging csv files without header into one txt file. But it's not working as well. Now with the converting csv into txt and then merging all files into one ("bigfile"), using dos2unix "bigfile" and then "!/Address/" is not working as well. I just get the same content as before plus some weird "chinese signs" at the end of the last column.

Comment: please edit your Q to show your current output (we need to see the "chinese" chars). Also, I'm not certain, did you try `dos2unix file1` with just 1 file and then `awk ... file1` , you should ;-). ... I understand what you're trying to do, (I think), but I can't see exactly what you are seeing because I don't have the same file and working environment. We'll have to take this piece by piece. Good luck.

Comment: I tried it with just one file using dos2unix file 1 and then gawk... file1. I added my "chinese signs" to my Q. Something is totally weird using gawk commands.

Comment: edit your Q to show output of `set | grep LANG` and `export | grep LANG` . AND `uname -srv`. Based on your `for /f` syntax and poswershell, you're using some Windows terminal program? How did you get `gawk` installed? Good luck.

Comment: AND do you see those chinese characters in your original file? Have you tried using your text editor to make a simple test file, and when you do, do the results change? Don't worry about combining files yet, let's get one file to work correctly , right ;-)? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, weekend was buys :/ I have no idea what you mean with grep and export functions or better: how to use them. I made every step so far just with one file. After changing xls to txt, using powershell to substitute tab with ; no chinese characters in the files. Only when I start using gawk commands (e.g. gawk "!/Address/") the characters are insert. I'm running Windows 7 at work, using gawk.exe of cgywin. I had another use of deleting lines in a txt files couple of months ago. There it worked perfectly. Without using any dos2unix, grep, set,...

Comment: my request for output from `set ..`, `export ..` and `uname` are intended to help debug the problem. If you have non-standard setting someplace, that may explain this weird behavior. You have covered the `uname` part in your reply above (using `cgywin`). But did you update any of the programs there. Without looking for `LANG*` variables in your environment, I'm out of ideas. Good luck.

Comment: When I run your command with the data you supplied it works for me, and it used to work for you, and I would bet it work for 99% of readers that would try it. So ... something in **your** setup has changed, and if you want to fix it, you'll have to focus a little more on debugging what the problem is. Good luck.